# How can I write a request spec with Capybara/RSpec for testing Sunspot/Solr searching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, solr, rspec, sunspot

I'd like to write my usual RSpec/Capybara request specs to test search functionality using Sunspot and Solr.  I've been digging around but can't find how to get this working.  I have the sunspot_test gem installed and have verified that the Products created do exist.  The issue seems to be with the indexing, maybe?  What am I missing?

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "search" do

  context "when searching by name/description" do

    let!(:super_mario_bros_3) { Factory(:product, :name => 'Super Mario Bros. 3') }
    let!(:legend_of_zelda)    { Factory(:product, :name => 'Legend of Zelda') }

    before { Product.reindex; Sunspot.commit }


    it "should only find games matching the search text", :js => true, :search => true do
      # search_for fills in and submits the search form
      search_for("Super")

      # This yields an empty array
      p Product.search { keyword "super" }.results

      # These fail
      page.should have_content super_mario_bros_3.name
      page.should have_no_content legend_of_zelda.name
    end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 5):

You're probably making the same mistake that I did. See the answer to my post here - [Sunspot and RSpec fail. The commit doesn't seem to be working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982349/sunspot-and-rspec-fail-the-commit-doesnt-seem-to-be-working)

Any test which uses Sunspot should be as follows....

```
describe "search", :search => true do
```

and make sure you have the following in your spec_helper.rb

```
require 'sunspot_test/rspec'
```