# Sunspot and RSpec fail. The commit doesn't seem to be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I've got a few tests running with RSpec for a Rails site, but despite
following the instructions things aren't quite behaving themselves.

I create an article via a Factory, run Sunspot.commit and then check
the results. I always seem to draw a blank though. When I test it
manually via the console or through the website it all works find
though.

Any ideas? How can I output the sunspot logs to see what's going on?

My Gemfile has the following, and I'm running Rails 3.1.1

```
gem 'sunspot', '1.2.1'
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'sunspot_test'
```

Many thanks,
Graeme

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was my fault for not reading the manual properly.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/sunspot_test/issues/9

It's necessary to add a magic bit to the description to make sure that Solr is started.

```
describe "my nice test", :search => true do
  thing = Factory.create(:thing)
  Sunspot.commit
  # do my search and test
  # now it works!
end
```

It's the **:search => true** that's important.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little something to the response above; if using FactoryGirl:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    after(:create) { Sunspot.commit } 
...
end
```

then you won't have to add the commit call on each test file...